# Python Selenium xpath with variable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I can't pass in a variable my search for xpath with selenium.
What is my mistake?

```
btn_login = "'.//a[contains(text(), 'Login to')]'"

btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'{btn_login}')))​

btn.click()
```

---

like that it works, I don't know if it's possible to use an f string in this case.

```
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, .//a[contains(text(), 'Login to')]')))

btn.click()
```

Comment: That xpath string literally contains the outermost single-quotes, which I don't think you intended.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `"Login to"` text to come from a variable, do it this way:

```
text = "whatever"
btn_login = f".//a[contains(text(), '{text}')]"

btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, btn_login)))​
```